# Where is rs2_device_info defined in details?

Tags: c++, realsense

I am exploring Intel's [librealsense](https://github.com/IntelRealSense/librealsense)  library.  Tracing the code, I can see that `rs2_device_info` is defined in [rs_types.h](https://github.com/IntelRealSense/librealsense/blob/master/include/librealsense2/h/rs_types.h)  as follows:

```
typedef struct rs2_device_info rs2_device_info;
```

However, it does not contain detailed the actual definition like `rs2_intrinsics` in the same file.  Could someone show me where it is?  How can the code compile if the actual definition is missing?  Thanks.

Comment: What are you asking? The definition of rs2_intrinsics is in that file.

Comment: @BTables, I am asking for the definition of rs2_device_info. I can only find the declaration there.

Comment: Okay, I understand now. I've updated with an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The definition of rs2_device_info can be found in ./src/context.h.

Specifically it is defined as:

```
struct rs2_device_info
{
    std::shared_ptr<librealsense::context> ctx;
    std::shared_ptr<librealsense::device_info> info;
};
```

As a note, after you clone the repo and navigate to the directory you can run the command

> grep -r . -e "struct rs2_device_info"

Comment: Thank you so much.  I am using the `sln` file that came with the RealSense SDK installer.  The example I am looking at is `rs-pointcloud.cpp` which is [here](https://github.com/IntelRealSense/librealsense/blob/master/examples/pointcloud/rs-pointcloud.cpp).  It has no reference to `context.h` in any way.  Can you tell how it will even compile?